# What is a photography release form? Do I need them for group shots?

Tags: legal, model-releases, canada

I'm an amateur photographer trying to build my portfolio, most so far with just family or animals. I sometimes post my shots on Facebook. I've been asked to photograph a band in a couple of weeks at one of their sets.

I'm not terribly familiar with release forms other than they allow me to monetize or otherwise attract business through use of photos of the people releasing their license to the photo. Do I need to bring a stack of releases and have everyone sign if I wanted to take wideangle group shots and put them on my Facebook?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is tagged w/ Canada, and the law in the common law provinces are the same as in the USA... a release form is only required if the image will be used commercially; and the release is required by the one using/publishing the image commercially, not necessarily the photographer (but the photographer is typically the one who obtains it).

However, in Quebec things are quite different... the relevant law is the civil privacy code; and you would likely need a release (permission) in order to make public any photo of any individual (other than news/journalism related).

see
https://digitalcommons.lmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1365&context=elr&httpsredir=1&referer=
and
[Aubrey v. Edition Vice-Versa Inc.](https://ambientlight.ca/laws/the-laws/provincial-law/quebec/human-rights-code/) (full court document [here](https://scc-csc.lexum.com/scc-csc/scc-csc/en/item/1608/index.do))